# Elegant solving and plotting of multivalued solutions for a system of 2 equations with parameters using NSolve?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, interpolation

**This looks long and complicated, but it's really not.  I just tried to pose the problem well.**

I have to solve a relatively complicated system of equations that has 2 variables and 3 parameters.

I start with some simplifications to make the equation readable:

```
Clear[z, F2, g, a]
z = 1;
aa[a_, aNL_] := a - aNL
gg[g_, gNL_] := Sqrt[g^2 + gNL^2]
```

These equations feed into the following system of two equations with two variables (aNL,gNL) which also depend on three input parameters (a,F2,g).  The system of equations is defined as `SLNS2` below.

```
SLNS2[aVal_, F2Val_, gVal_] := 
 NSolve[{aNL == (2 z + 1)/2 F2 (
      1 + (aa[a, aNL] - gNL)^2 + 
       gg[g, gNL]^2)/((1 + gg[g, gNL]^2 - aa[a, aNL]^2)^2 + 
       4 aa[a, aNL]^2), 
    gNL == (2 z - 1)/2 F2 (
      1 + (aa[a, aNL] - gNL)^2 - 
       g^2)/((1 + gg[g, gNL]^2 - aa[a, aNL]^2)^2 + 
       4 aa[a, aNL]^2)} /. {a -> aVal, F2 -> F2Val, g -> gVal}, {aNL, 
   gNL}, Reals]
```

Note, that in order to explore the dependence of the solutions to specific values of input parameters I used `/. {a -> aVal, F2 -> F2Val, g -> gVal}`.

For certain input parameters the system of equations is single valued in (aNL,gNL):

```
SLNS2[2, 30, 0.01]
```

For other input parameter values, the system is multivalued with up to 5 unique solutions:

```
SLNS2[14.5, 30, 0.01]
```

The next goal was building functions (or at least curves) for each variable against the input parameter `a`, leaving the other two parameters (F2,g) as input parameters.

**Single-valued Solutions**

To construct these curves I made a 2-column list for both "aNL vs a" and "gNL vs a" using `LISTaNL` and `LISTgNL` respectively.

```
aMIN1 = -30;
aMAX1 = +10;

LISTaNL[F2Val_, gVal_, aSTEP_] := 
 Table[{aVal, SLNS2[aVal, F2Val, gVal][[1]][[1]][[2]]}, {aVal, aMIN1, 
   aMAX1, aSTEP}]

LISTgNL[F2Val_, gVal_, aSTEP_] := 
 Table[{aVal, SLNS2[aVal, F2Val, gVal][[1]][[2]][[2]]}, {aVal, aMIN1, 
   aMAX1, aSTEP}]
```

In the above functions the [[1]][[1]][[2]] serve to pick out the numerical value of `aNL` or `gNL` in each solution.  To see how this works run the code below.

```
SLNS2[-20, 30, 1]
SLNS2[-20, 30, 1][[1]]
SLNS2[-20, 30, 1][[1]][[1]]
SLNS2[-20, 30, 1][[1]][[1]][[2]] (*isolate aNL value*)
SLNS2[-20, 30, 1][[1]][[2]][[2]] (*isolate gNL value*)
```

Sample output is below

```
aNLsingle = LISTaNL[30, 1, 2];
gNLsingle = LISTgNL[30, 1, 2];

ListPlot[{aNLsingle, gNLsingle}, PlotRange -> {{-30, 60}, {-2, 60}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "aNL or gNL"}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, fontsize, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Sample single-valued solutions", fontsize, Bold, Black], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"aNL", "gNL"},(*LegendFunction\[Rule]"Frame",*)
    LegendMarkerSize -> 15, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", 16], 
    LegendLayout -> "Column"], {0.26, 0.575}]]
```

**Multi-valued Solutions**

All of the important information from these curves is in the multi-valued regions.  The simple approach above fails when it's multivalued because it only grabs the first solution.

My current (silly) method for dealing with this is to:

1. List item Construct multiple curves for each of the 5 solutions
2. List item Delete non-numerical entries with `Select[,#[[2]]>0&]`
3. List item Join the 5 solutions together into one list.

(Note that to see the multivalued solutions I've increased the range of `a` values)

```
aMIN2 = -30;
aMAX2 = 40;

LISTaNLi[F2Val_, gVal_, aSTEP_, i_] := 
 Select[Table[{aVal, SLNS2[aVal, F2Val, gVal][[i]][[1]][[2]]}, {aVal, 
    aMIN2, aMAX2, aSTEP}], #[[2]] > 0 &]
LISTgNLi[F2Val_, gVal_, aSTEP_, i_] := 
 Select[Table[{aVal, SLNS2[aVal, F2Val, gVal][[i]][[2]][[2]]}, {aVal, 
    aMIN2, aMAX2, aSTEP}], #[[2]] > 0 &]
```

Joining the lists together

```
LISTaNLall[F2Val_, gVal_, aSTEP_] := 
 Join[LISTaNLi[F2Val, gVal, aSTEP, 1], 
  LISTaNLi[F2Val, gVal, aSTEP, 2], LISTaNLi[F2Val, gVal, aSTEP, 3], 
  LISTaNLi[F2Val, gVal, aSTEP, 4], LISTaNLi[F2Val, gVal, aSTEP, 5]]

LISTgNLall[F2Val_, gVal_, aSTEP_] := 
 Join[LISTgNLi[F2Val, gVal, aSTEP, 1], 
  LISTgNLi[F2Val, gVal, aSTEP, 2], LISTgNLi[F2Val, gVal, aSTEP, 3], 
  LISTgNLi[F2Val, gVal, aSTEP, 4], LISTgNLi[F2Val, gVal, aSTEP, 5]]
```

And here's a sample plot of the output (this will probably take about 60s to run. If it's too slow, increase `aSTEP` to something like 5):

```
aNLmulti = LISTaNLall[30, 1, 0.5];
gNLmulti = LISTgNLall[30, 1, 0.5];

ListPlot[{aNLmulti, gNLmulti}, PlotRange -> {{-30, 60}, {-2, 60}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"a", "aNL or gNL"}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, fontsize, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Sample multi-valued solutions", fontsize, Bold, Black], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"aNL", "gNL"},(*LegendFunction\[Rule]"Frame",*)
    LegendMarkerSize -> 15, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", 16], 
    LegendLayout -> "Column"], {0.26, 0.575}]]
```

(FYI, don't worry about the errors for now, it's just complaining about things like the 2nd solution doesn't exist in all regions.  These datapoints are removed with `Select`)

**The Problem**

My approach takes way too much computation time.  In my current method, I have to solve for all the solutions a redundant five times (because I just take the relevant element for the i^th solution).  Is there a more elegant way to do this so that my computation times aren't 5 times as long as they have to be?

**How do I get mathematica to not output data as a 'nested list' and just output all of the solutions as a simple list in the first place?  **

**Bonus Questions**

`Interpolation` fails when applied `LISTaNLall[F2Val_, gVal_, aSTEP_]`.  Is there some way to construct an interpolating for multivalued curves so that you can evaluate at arbitrary points (within reason)?

ListLinePLot is a disaster for the same reason.  Is there a way to tell mathematica how to follow the curves (without ordering the lists by hand)?  What would this even be called?  Any relevant search terms?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me point out that you could much more simply use something like `Plot[aNL /. SLNS2[aVal, 30, 1], {aVal, aMIN1, aMAX1}]` and get a good plot much more succinctly, while taking advantage of `Plot`'s adaptive sampling capabilities. Consider also that, instead of the fragile `SLNS2[-20, 30, 1][[1]][[2]][[2]]` (which, by the way, you could write as `SLNS2[-20, 30, 1][[1, 2, 2]]`), you should really try to use something like `gNL /. SLNS2[-20, 30, 1]`.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the tip.  The nomenclature is definitely cleaned up but it still has the fundamental problem of missing the multivalued regions.      ```aNLmultiCOARSE = LISTaNLall[30, 1, 2];

Show[
 ListPlot[aNLmultiCOARSE, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-32, 52}, {-1, 59}}, Frame -> True],
 Plot[aNL /. SLNS2[aVal, 30, 1], {aVal, -30, 59}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{-32, 52}, {-1, 59}}]
 ]
```